# Split a single Excel column into multiple columns in excel

Tags: excel

I have a data set of five years and each day consists of 24 observations presented in a single column mean first 24 observations of day 1 followed by the next 24 observations of the day2 similarly for all five years, so I want to split this single excel column into 24 columns (meaning that a single row having 24 observations each) represents a single day.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please refer to [ask] a question with an [mcve] and edit your quesiton accordingly. SO is not a free coding service.

Comment: Is each observation in a single cell or do you have cells containing multiple observations?

Comment: I have a single observation in each cell

Comment: I have a single column for all the data consist of  43,848 observations, I want to split into 24 columns and 1827 rows to this single column data

Answer (score 0):

The title of your question doesn't seem to match the text of the question.

If you have multiple observations, one in each cell, going down a single column you could use `INDEX` to 'split' the data into rows of 24 columns.

For example, if the data is currently in column A starting at row 1 you could put this formula in B1 and copy it across and down.

```swift
=INDEX($A:$A,COLUMN()-1+24*(ROW()-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to split the single column that has observations for a day into 24 columns, then:
1)select the column
2) click on Data tab
3) click on "Text to Columns" under Data tools.
4)If the data in the column is separated by commas, then select the delimiter as commas (or select whatever delimiter was used to separate the 24 observations)
5)click Finish.

this will split the data in a single column into separate columns.